# NASM Can you explain to me why my code is returning a segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

My code returns a segmentation fault on the second call to subroutine `prntlf`.

```
_start:
mov     ecx, msg
call prntlf

call prntlf ; Here is where the issue is
```

After experimentation, I found that it only occurs when I don't set the value of `ecx` back to the string I want it to print, but what I want to know is why I have to do that. Given I popped the value of the registers off the saved stack, shouldn't `ecx` still hold a valid string to print?

Full source:

File `hello.asm`:

```
; RUN WITH `nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello.o && ld -m elf_i386 hello.o -o hello && ./hello`

%include 'subroutines.inc'

section .data
    msg         db      "Hello, World!", 0x0
    msg2         db      "Goodbye, Moon!", 0x0
    linefeed    db      0xA, 0xD

section .text
    global _start:

_start:
    mov     ecx, msg
    call prntlf

    call prntlf

    jmp     end
```

File: `subroutines.inc`

```
    ; subroutines.inc


;===============================================================================
    ; getstrlen | Gets String Length and pushes the value to register edx
    ;===============================================================================
    getstrlen:
        push    eax
        push    ebx
        mov     eax, ebx

    findnterm:
        cmp     byte [eax], 0
        jz      gotstrlen
        inc     eax
        jmp     findnterm

    gotstrlen:
        sub     eax, ebx
        mov     edx, eax
        pop     eax
        pop     ebx
        ret

    ;===============================================================================
    ; printstr | Prints a String using a dynamic algorithm to find null terminator
    ;===============================================================================
    printstr:
        push    eax
        push    ebx
        push    edx

        mov     ebx, ecx
        call getstrlen

        mov     ebx, 0x01
        mov     eax, 0x04
        int 0x80

        pop     eax
        pop     ebx
        pop     edx
        ret

    ;===============================================================================
    ; prntlf | Prints a String and appends a Linefeed.
    ;===============================================================================
    prntlf:
        push    eax
        push    ebx
        push    ecx
        push    edx

        mov     eax, ecx

    movetoendloop:
        cmp     byte [eax], 0
        jz      donemoving
        inc     eax
        jmp     movetoendloop

    donemoving:
        call printstr
        mov     ecx, linefeed
        call printstr

        pop     eax
        pop     ebx
        pop     ecx
        pop     edx
        ret

    ;===============================================================================
    ; end | calls kernel and tells it to End the program
    ;===============================================================================
    end:
        mov     eax, 0x01
        mov     ebx, 0x00
        int 0x80
```

Comment: When you push things on the stack you need to pop them off in reverse order. Your function like `printlf` doesn't pop them off in reverse order. You make the same mistake in most other functions as well (you need to fix all the functions).Example if you do `push eax` `push ebx` `push ecx` `push edx` you need to pop them off in this order `pop edx` `pop ecx` `pop ebx` `pop eax` . Since you are popping things off in the wrong order the registers are getting different values than expected and thus _ECX_ doesn't appear to be preserved across function calls leading to problems like the one you see.

Comment: Single step this with a debugger to test your assumptions and find out that you swap `ebx` and `ecx`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thats it, thanks so much! I can't believe this book didn't say you needed to pop em off in reverse order.

Comment: The book/tutorial may assume you understand the mechanics of how a stack works. There is a reasonable description here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack  . A stack is a last in first out structure.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Would you like to put that in an answer format so I may accept it and close the question?

Comment: You can self answer this question if you wish. Answering your own question is perfectly fine on StackkOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack is a Last-in-First-out structure, meaning that the last thing you pushed into the stack will be the first thing popped out, no matter the register you pop it into.

```
prntlf:
    push    eax
    push    ebx
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    ...

    pop     edx       ; Pop them back from the stack in the reverse order in which you pushed them.
    pop     ecx
    pop     ebx
    pop     eax
    ret
```